# Is Mongoose not scalable with document array editing and version control?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am developing a web application with Node.js and MongoDB/Mongoose. Our most used Model, Record, has many subdocument arrays. Some of these, for instance, include "Comment", "Bookings", and "Subscribers".

In the client side application, whenever the user hits the "delete" button it fires off an AJAX request to the delete route for that specific comment. The problem I am running into is that, when many of these AJAX calls come in at once, Mongoose fails with a "Document not found" error on some (but not all) of the calls.

This *only* happens when the calls are made rapidly and many at a time. I think this is due to the version in Mongoose causing document conflicts. Our current process for a delete is:

1. Fetch the document using `Record.findById()`
2. Remove the subdocument from the appropriate array (using, say, `comment.remove()`)
3. Call `record.save()`

I have found a solution where I can manually update the collection using `Record.findByIdAndUpdate` and then using the `$pull` operator. However, this means we can't use any of mongoose's middleware and loose the version control entirely. And the more I think about it, the more I realize situations where this would happen and I would have to use Mongoose's wrapper functions like `findByIdAndUpdate` or `findAndRemove`. The only other solution I can think of would be to put the removal attempt into a `while` loop and hope it works, which seems like a very poor fix.

Using the Mongoose wrappers doesn't really solve my problem as it won't allow me to use any sort of Middleware or hooks at all then, which is basically one of the huge benefits of using Mongoose.

Does this mean that Mongoose is essentially useless for anything of with rapid editing and I might as well just use native MongoDB drivers? Am I misunderstanding Mongoose's limitations?
How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mongoose's versioned document array editing is not scalable for the simple reason that it's not an atomic operation.  As a result, the more array edit activity you have, the more likely it is that two edits will collide and you'll suffer the overhead of retry/recovery from that in your code.

For scalable document array manipulation, you have to use `update` with the atomic array update [operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/#operators): `$pull[All]`, `$push[All]`, `$pop`, `$addToSet`, and `$`.  Of course, you can also use these operators with the atomic `findAndModify`-based methods of `findByIdAndUpdate` and `findOneAndUpdate` if you also need the original or resulting doc.

As you mentioned, the big downside of using `update` instead of `findOne`+`save` is that none of your Mongoose middleware and validation is executed during an `update`.  But I don't see that you have any choice if you want a scalable system.  I'd much rather manually duplicate some middleware and validation logic for the update case than have to suffer the scalability penalties of using Mongoose's versioned document array editing.  Hey, at least you still get the benefits of Mongoose's schema-based type casting on updates!

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but the one that makes the most sense. Thanks for providing a proper scalable workaround!

Answer (score 3):

I *think*, from our own experiences, the answer to your question is "yes". Mongoose is *not* scalable for rapid array-based updates.

#### Background

We're experiencing the same issue at [HabitRPG](https://habitrpg.com/). After a recent surge in user growth (bringing our DB to 6gb), we started experiencing `VersionError` for many array-based updates ([background on VersionError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499089/versionerror-no-matching-document-found-error-on-node-js-mongoose)). `ensureIndex({_id:1,__v1:1})` helped a bit, but that tapered as yet more users joined. It would appear to me Mongoose is indeed not scalable for array-based updates. You can see our whole [investigation process here](https://github.com/HabitRPG/habitrpg/issues/2301).

#### Solution

If you can afford moving from an array to an object, do that. Eg, `comments: Schema.Types.Array` => `comments: Schema.Types.Mixed`, and sort by `post.comments.{ID}.date`, or even a manual `post.comments.{ID}.position` if necessary.

If you're stuck with arrays:

1. `db.collection.ensureIndex({_id:1,__v:1})`
2. Use your methods described above. You won't benefit from hooks and validations, but there are worse things.

Comment: how can a replica set help here? it's for high availability. the OP (and you) need faster processing or writes (or more writes in parallel)  which can only be achieved by sharding.

Comment: You're right. I hadn't realized all writes go to the master, and the replicas are only used for reads. Updated.

Comment: As the top comment recommended, trying to use atomic operations where possible makes more sense to me than using objects. Thank for you for linking Github issue discussion though, it's a very interesting read!

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest pulling those arrays out into new collections.  For example, a Comments collection where each document has a record ID to indicate where it belongs.  This is a much more scalable solution.

You are correct, Mongoose's array operations are not atomic and therefore do not scale well.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of another idea, which I'm not certain about but seems worth offering: soft-delete.

Mongoose is very concerned about array-structure changes because they make future changes ambiguous. But if you were to just tag a comment subdocument with `comment.deleted=true` then you might be able to do more such operations without encountering conflicts. Then you could have a cron task that goes through and actually removes those comments.

Oh, an additional idea is to use some sort of memory cache, so if an record has been accessed/edited in the last few minutes, it's available without having to pull it from the server, which means that two requests coming in at the same time are going to be modifying the same object.

Note: I'm not actually sure that *either* of these are good ideas in general or that they'll solve your problem, so go ahead and edit/comment/downvote if they're bad :)

Comment: I believe this would have a similar problem. I think any changes to the document will cause the version to be incremented (either setting a field to `true` or removing an array element), which will then be rejected when attempting to call `update()`, although correct me if that's mistaken.