# "VersionError: No matching document found" error on Node.js/Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm relatively new to Node.js and Mongo/Mongoose, and I'm having a *very* difficult time troubleshooting a specific Mongoose error:

**VersionError: No matching document found.**

*(Entire error trace/stack at the bottom of this question.)*

This blog post pretty clearly outline how a VersionError might occur:

- http://aaronheckmann.blogspot.com/2012/06/mongoose-v3-part-1-versioning.html

*(TL;DR - "Mongoose v3 now adds a schema-configurable version key to each document. This value is atomically incremented whenever a modification to an array potentially changes any array’s elements position." If you try to save a document, but the version key no longer matches the object you have retrieved, you get the above `VersionError`.)*

**Core Question:** Is there some way to display the offending `save()` operation? Or which document failed to save? Or *anything* at all?! ;)

**The Challenge:** this is a relatively large code base with many arrays, and I am unsure how to begin to troubleshoot the problem. In particular, the error trace/stack does NOT seem to show where the problem exists. See below:

```
VersionError: No matching document found.
at handleSave (<project_path>/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:121:23)
at exports.tick (<project_path>/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:408:16)
at null.<anonymous> (<project_path>/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection.js:484:9)
at g (events.js:192:14)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
at Server.Base._callHandler (<project_path>/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:391:25)
at Server.connect.connectionPool.on.server._serverState (<project_path>/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:558:20)
at MongoReply.parseBody (<project_path>/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:131:5)
at Server.connect.connectionPool.on.server._serverState (<project_path>/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:517:22)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
```

Comment: Perhaps turning on debug ([docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-set)) might help you track down this problem. I recently had the same issue, turned out that I was saving the same document instance two times, concurrently.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Per request, here is an outline of our problem, and how we resolved it:

In our system we created a custom Document locking routine (using redis-lock), wherein the following happened in this precise (incorrect) order:

**INCORRECT ORDER OF OPERATIONS:**

1. Client request received
2. Document locked
3. Document retrieved
4. Document edited
5. Document unlocked
6. Client request resolved
7. *Document saved*

Once you see it written out, the problem is obvious: we were saving our Documents outside our Document lock.

Let's assume #6 takes 100ms in our system. That is a 100ms window wherein if any other requests grabs that same Document, we're going to have a save conflict (the titled error in this Question is basically a save conflict IMHO).

In other words/example: in our system, Request A grabbed Version 1 of Document X, edited it, then unlocked it, but before Request A saved the Document, Request B grabbed Document X and incremented it to Version 2 (read up on Mongo versions for more info about this). Then Request A resolves its Client request and goes to save Document X, but it's trying to save Version 1, and now it sees it has Version 2, and thus the error above.

So the fix is easy. Save your Documents inside your lock. (In the above example, move #7 to before #5. See below.)

**CORRECT/FIXED ORDER OF OPERATIONS**

1. Client request received
2. Document locked
3. Document retrieved
4. Document edited
5. *Document saved*
6. Document unlocked
7. Client request resolved

(You could make an argument that #6 and #7 should be swapped, but that is outside the scope of Mongo/Mongoose/this question.)

I am going to leave this question un-answered for a while and see if anyone can shed some light on a better way to isolate the relevant code and troubleshoot this issue. In our case, this was a very systemic problem and VERY challenging to troubleshoot for our skill level at the time.

Comment: I've been dealing with similar issues here and there myself.  One thing that fixed a lot of the issues was to ensure that all .save()'s have callbacks and making sure saves are sequential. `item.save(function(){ item.save( [...] ); })`  I'm also working on catching the error and refetching/ resaving the document post-error ([somewhat along these lines](https://gist.github.com/droppedonjapan/5483a81917ea37ef381b)).  Still trying to figure out the specifics for not only catching the error, but the old document as well.

Comment: I'm having this error even when my save() calls aren't concurrent. Relevant: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1844 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723474/version-error-on-saving-mongoose-docs

Comment: @toblerpwn we are having the same issue in our application. Do you think using redis-lock was a strong solution? It's one of the options we are considering.

Comment: `redis-lock` has been good to us for several years now, yes, particularly when several documents must be edited in serial and in concert. i would verify that your use cases actually require a lock, however; I believe with WiredTiger (and possibly before), MongoDB has good document-level locking built-in for many cases. but not all. and we use `redis-lock` for the edge cases.

Answer (score 11):

It propably points to saving the same document concurrently as robertklep points out.

We had a similar issue running concurrent saves on the same document using async.parallel.

Comment: Indeed; I think this was basically an issue specific to our environment, which I found only by copious `console.log`ing. I think the key question remains (which I will edit + highlight better): is there a way to log the failing save out of Mongoose directly? That would help future searchers. :)

Comment: @toblerpwn - could you elaborate on what you think caused this?

Comment: @UpTheCreek - definitely. I'll create another answer for this. Stand by.

Comment: i'm still standing...better than i ever did...looking like a true survivor...feeling like a little kid

Answer (score 8):

This error can also occur when your process maintains an outdated version of a document in memory and then tries to save it at some point after it has been updated by another process.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when i tried to update a user's reference IDs to an email. The fix was really simple with async / await! Here the code snippet, hope it helps.

```
email
    .save()
    .then(() =>
      User.findById(email.from).then(async sender => { // declare function as async
        sender.emails.sent.push(email._id);
        await sender.save(); // wait for save() to complete before proceeding
      }).catch((err) => console.log(err))
    )
    .then(() =>
      User.findById(email.to).then(async receiver => { // same as above
        receiver.emails.received.push(email._id);
        await receiver.save(); // same as above
      }).catch((err) => console.log(err))
    )
    .then(() => res.status(200).json({ message: successMessage }))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because I was removing an item from an array of a Document using `splice` function.

I fixed replacing `splice` function with `pull` function from [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#removing-subdocs).