# Version error on saving Mongoose docs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an issue - not sure if I am doing something wrong or it's a bug. I have some products - each of these has an array of variations. I want to go through some data and load it in these variations but I experience a number of 'VersionError: No matching document found' errors.

Thinking I was having a race condition (I am sequenctially saving the same document for each of its variations that I modify) I used asyc.eachSeries() but that did not help. Loading the error causing documents one at the time does not yield the error so it seems related to some race condition but I cannot track it down.

Schema:

```
var Product = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
  },  
  variations: {
    type: Array
  }
});
```

Sample code:

```
// Some data to load - the 'variant' is the index of the variations array above
var records = [{
  code: 'foo',
  id: '50ba9c647abe1789f7000073',
  variant: 0
}, {
  code: 'bar',
  id: '50ba9c647abe1789f7000073',
  variant: 1
}, {
  code: 'foobar',
  id: '50ba9c647abe1789f7000073',
  variant: 2
}];

var iterator = function(item, cb) {
  Product.findById(item.id).exec(function(err, product) {
    if(err) {
      return cb(err);
    }
    if (product) {
      product.variations[item.variant].code = item.code.trim();
      product.markModified('variations');
      product.save(function(err, p) {
        return cb(err);
      });
    } else {
      return cb('Missing product');
    }
  });
};

async.eachSeries(records, iterator, function(err) {
  process.exit(1);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is how you've defined your schema. It's much to better to have variant be it's own schema and have the product schema use that as a sub doc instead. I would change it to look something like this:

```
var Variant = new Schema({
    code: String,
})

var Product = new Schema({
    title: String,
    variants: [Variant]
})
```

Then you could go through the records like so:

```
var variants = product.variants
for (i in variants) {
    var variant = variants[i]
    variant.code = records[i].code
    variant.save(function(err) {
        ...
    })
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Listed above: VersionError: No matching document found

Comment: Hmm.. If you are saving the same object in two different asyncronous callbacks that could be the reason for this error. Are you calling your iterator method for the same product multiple times? Then the `product.save(function(err, p) { ... }` could be the cause of it. Try to run the code once and see if the error still occur.

Comment: I think that it is indeed a double save issue - I modified the code to load the object once, update all variations and save and that works. But why doesn't the async.eachSeries work?  Perhaps I am not using that correctly. I  might rephrase this question

Comment: @materik You sir saved me a great headache.

Answer (score 1):

If in model Scheme you using versionKey the problem can come when, doc called from mongo multiple times, In that case the best way is send all object of doc, near example

```
function getDoc(doc, callback) {
    if ( doc instanceof Object && doc._id ) {
        callback(null, doc);
    } else {
        return Doc.findById(doc, callback);
    }
}

function updateDoc(doc, data) {
   // doc is already model
   getDoc(doc, function(err, doc) {
       doc.data = data;
       doc.save();
   });
}
```