# Mongoose: Incrementing my documents version number doesn't work, and I'm getting a Version Error when I try to save

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I try to save my document, I'm getting a `VersionError: No matching document found` error, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499089/versionerror-no-matching-document-found-error-on-node-js-mongoose) SO question.

After reading [this](http://aaronheckmann.tumblr.com/post/48943525537/mongoose-v3-part-1-versioning) blog post, it seems that the problem is with the versioning of my document. That I'm messing with an array and so I need to update the version.

However, calling `document.save()` doesn't work for me. When I log out the document before and after the call to `save()`, `document._v` is the same thing.

I also tried doing `document._v = document._v++` which also didn't work.

---

**Code**

```
exports.update = function(req, res) {
  if (req.body._id) { delete req.body._id; }
  User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, user) {
    if (err) return handleError(res, err);
    if (!user) return res.send(404);
    var updated = _.extend(user, req.body); // doesn't increment the version number. causes problems with saving. see http://aaronheckmann.blogspot.com/2012/06/mongoose-v3-part-1-versioning.html
    console.log('pre increment: ', updated);
    updated.increment();
    // updated._v = updated._v++;
    console.log('post increment: ', updated);
    updated.save(function(err) {
      if (err) return handleError(res, err);
      return res.json(200, user);
    });
  });
};
```

**Output**

```
pre increment:  { _id: 5550baae1b571aafa52f070c,
  provider: 'local',
  name: 'Adam',
  email: 'azerner3@gmail.com',
  hashedPassword: '/vahOqXwCwKQKtcV3KBQeFge/YB0xtqOj+YDyck7gzyALA/IP7u7BfqQhlVHBQT26//XfBTkaOCK2bQXg65OzA==',
  salt: 'MvzXW7D4xuyGQBJNeFRoUg==',
  __v: 32,
  drafts: [],
  starredSkims: [],
  skimsCreated: [ 5550cfdab8dcacd1a7892aa4 ],
  role: 'user' }

post increment:  { _id: 5550baae1b571aafa52f070c,
  provider: 'local',
  name: 'Adam',
  email: 'azerner3@gmail.com',
  hashedPassword: '/vahOqXwCwKQKtcV3KBQeFge/YB0xtqOj+YDyck7gzyALA/IP7u7BfqQhlVHBQT26//XfBTkaOCK2bQXg65OzA==',
  salt: 'MvzXW7D4xuyGQBJNeFRoUg==',
  __v: 32,
  drafts: [],
  starredSkims: [],
  skimsCreated: [ 5550cfdab8dcacd1a7892aa4 ],
  role: 'user' }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here has to do with using `__v` and trying to update it manually.  `.increment` does not actually perform an increment immediately, but it does set an internal flag for the model to handle incrementing.  I can't find any documentation on `.increment`, so I assume it is probably for use internally.  The problem stems from trying to combine `.extend` with an object that already has `__v` (there are two underscores by the way, not that `document.__v++` affects the model internally anyway) in addition to using `.increment`.

When you use `_.extend` it copies the `__v` property directly onto the object which seems to cause problems because Mongoose cannot find the old version internally.  I didn't dig deep enough to find why this is specifically, but you can get around it by also adding `delete req.body.__v`.

Rather than finding and saving as two steps, you can also use [`.findByIdAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate). Note that this does *not* use `__v` or increment it internally. As the other answer and linked bug indicate, if you want to increment the version during an update you have to do so manually.

Answer (score 0):

Versioning was implemented to mitigate the `doc.save()` by design (not Model.update etc). But if you want you can try the following instead:

```
{$set: {dummy: [2]}, $inc: { __v: 1 }}
```

However this was a confirmed-bug according to the [link](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1265)

Please validate your mongoose version from the milestone of the above issue.

Thanks :)

Comment: "Versioning was implemented to mitigate the doc.save() by design (not Model.update etc)" - I don't understand what that means. "confirmed-bug" - that looks like it's talking about `update` and `findByIdAndUpdate`, but I'm not doing either of those (I used the word "update" by mistake in my question, but my code shows that I'm calling `save()`)