# simulate mongodb race condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I got `"Error: error occured while saving model: VersionError: No matching document found for id "5bb83342342342348a5"` from a legacy code.

(relate: ["VersionError: No matching document found" error on Node.js/Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499089/versionerror-no-matching-document-found-error-on-node-js-mongoose))

The issue was due to saving a very large dataset (several gigs, took 2 days to create).

Now, I'm trying to reproduce the error, but I don't want to spend 2~4 days to reproduce things. Is there a way to artificially make the lock-unlock phase longer?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to save a document which has been modified since you retrieved it. Here is an example of how to reproduce it :

```
// Get the same document twice
const data1 = await model.findOne(...);
const data2 = await model.findOne(...);

data1.someField = x;
data2.someField = y;

await data1.save();

// save is going to throw
await data2.save();
```