# Express server stops after 5 GET requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, express

This code works like it should work, but after fifth **GET** request it does what it should do on the backend(stores the data in db) but it's not logging anything on the server and no changes on frontend(reactjs)

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('./login').User;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/animationsdb');

router.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    await User.findOne({ username: req.query.username }, (err, result) => {
        if (result) {
            // when user goes to his profile we send him the list of animations he liked
            // list is stored in array at db, field likedAnimations
            res.send({ animationList: result.likedAnimations });
            console.log("Lajkovane animacije:", result.likedAnimations);
        } else {
            console.log("no result found");
            res.sendStatus(404)
        }
    });
});

router.put('/', async(req, res) => {
    console.log("username:", req.body.username);
    console.log("link:", req.body.link);

    // if animation is already liked, then dislike it
    // if it's not liked, then store it in db
    const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
    if (user.likedAnimations.indexOf(req.body.link) === -1) {
        user.likedAnimations.push(req.body.link);
    } else {
        user.likedAnimations = arrayRemove(user.likedAnimations, user.likedAnimations[user.likedAnimations.indexOf(req.body.link)]);
    }
    user.save();
});

function arrayRemove(arr, value) {
    return arr.filter((item) => {
        return item != value;
    });
}

module.exports = router;
```

For first five requests I get this output:

```
Liked animations: ["/animations/animated-button.html"]
GET /animation-list/?username=marko 200 5.152 ms - 54
Liked animations: ["/animations/animated-button.html"]
GET /animation-list/?username=marko 304 3.915 ms - -
```

After that I don't get any output on server console and no changes on front end untill I refresh the page, even though db operations still work and data is saved.

Comment: This request handler has two code paths that send no response at all.  1) If `User.findOne()` fails and rejects or 2) if `result` is falsey (nothing found).  You should be sending an appropriate response in both those cases.  Whenever something suspicious is happening, the first thing I do is go investigate my error handling and see if something is happening that I'm not handling properly.  In addition, you can log all possible code paths on the server and see if you're even getting a request and, if so, what path it is taking.  You can likely solve this with more logging.

Comment: Open the Chrome debugger and look at the network tab and see exactly what the server is returning to you when you make these client requests that don't seem to display anything.

Comment: Plus, that code doesn't save anything to the DB?

Comment: @ChrisG it triggers the code that saves

Comment: @jfriend00, I got this error now: express UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: VersionError: No matching document found for id

Comment: Well, there you go.  You have a database error.  Here's some discussion of [that database error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499089/versionerror-no-matching-document-found-error-on-node-js-mongoose).  Other than handling all your errors and sending an appropriate response, you don't show us enough code for us to know how to prevent this error.  It is probably caused by some sort of concurrency error (conflicting database operations in operation at the same time).  Read the other answers in this link for ideas.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ok, I'll read it now, but I noticed this on network tab: my last request is pending, first five request are resolved and got the status 200 but for last request it says pending

Comment: Yeah, it's sitll pending because you never send ANY response when an error happens.  It will be pending until eventually the browser times it out since your server never sends a response. Please reread my first comment here.  Handle all possible errors on the server and always send a response to ever request, even in all error conditions.

Comment: @jfriend00 should I add something like this after is statement:
else {
            throw new Error('error occurred');
        }

Comment: @AndrijaGajic - NO.  That doesn't send an error response.  Something like this in the `else` does: `console.log("no result found"); res.sendStatus(404)`'.  And, you also have to put a `try/catch` around your `await` in order to catch rejections from the database (which is apparently what is really happening here).  But, this is just properly handling errors - this isn't preventing the error in the first place.  We'd have to see the rest of the related code (such as the related code that writes to the database) to be able to help any further with that part of the problem.

Comment: The code you posted only contains a query that reads the DB (User.findOne), nothing that writes anything to it.

Comment: How and when is your client-side code making these requests? You tagged this with React, so my guess is there's an issue with your fetch code. What if you put the GET url in the browser's address bar and refresh a bunch of times instead? Does it also stop working after 5 requests?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have a couple issues going on.  First, this request handler is not properly coded to handle errors and thus it leaves requests as pending and does not send a response and the connection will stay as pending until the client eventually times it out.  Second, you likely have some sort of database concurrency usage error that is the root issue here.  Third, you're not using `await` properly with your database.  You either use `await` or you pass a callback to your database, not both.  You need to fix all three of these.

To address the first and third issues:

```
router.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        let result = await User.findOne({ username: req.query.username };
        if (result) {
            console.log("Liked animations:", result.likedAnimations);
            res.send({ animationList: result.likedAnimations });
        } else {
            console.log("no database result found");
            res.sendStatus(404);
        }
   } catch(e) {
       console.log(e);
       res.sendStatus(500);
   }
});
```

For the second issue, the particular database error you mention appears to be some sort of concurrency/locking issue internal to the database and is triggered by the sequence of database operations your code executes.  You can read more about that error in the [discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499089/versionerror-no-matching-document-found-error-on-node-js-mongoose).  Since the code you show us only shows a single read operation, we would need to see a much larger context of relevant code including the code related to this operation that writes to the database in order to be able to offer any ideas on how to fix the root cause of this issue.

We can't see the whole flow here, but you need to use atomic update operations in your database. Your PUT handler you show is an immediate race condition. In multi-client databases, you don't get a value, modify it and then write it back. That's an opportunity for a race condition because someone else could modify the value while you're sitting their holding it.  When you then modify your held value, you overwrite the change that the other client just made.  That's a race condition.  Instead, you use an atomic operation that updates the operation directly in one database call or you use transactions to make a multi-step operation into a safe operation.

I'd suggest you read [this article](https://adrianmejia.com/how-to-perform-atomic-operations-on-mongodb/) on atomic operations in mongodb.  And, probably you want to use something like `.findAndModify()` so you can find and change an item in the database in one atomic operation.  If you search for "atomic operations in mongodb", there are many other articles on the topic.

Comment: else {
            console.log("no database result found");
            res.sendStatus(404);
        }
I added this code and it logs this after some time(probably when client connection ends), I'll add rest of the code now

Comment: Hopefully now it's easier to see what's going on

Comment: @AndrijaGajic - Yes, that's the idea behind comprehensive error handling and appropriate logging.  Keep in mind, you should write your server-side code this way from the beginning, not just when you have a problem to debug.  I would guess you also need this type of logging in whatever server-side functions are writing to the database.

Comment: So how do I fix this in the end, I mean I have nice error log, but problem is still there. If I  got it right the problem is the order of operations, the client gets the old version of document and tries to modify it and then conflict occurs?

Comment: @AndrijaGajic - We can't see the whole flow here, but probably, you need to use atomic update operations.  Your PUT handler you show is an immediately race condition.  In multi-client databases, you don't get a value, modify it and then write it back.  That's an opportunity for a race condition.  Instead, you use an atomic operation that updates the operation directly in one database call or you use transactions to make a multi-step operation into a safe operation.

Comment: @AndrijaGajic - I'd suggest you read [this article](https://adrianmejia.com/how-to-perform-atomic-operations-on-mongodb/) on atomic operations in mongodb.  And, probably you want to use something like `.findAndModify()`.